# Как в python реализовать проверку значения на то, к какому значению списка оно ближе

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список: `[0.3, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]`

Как мне проверить значение полученное ранее на то, к какому из значений данного списка оно ближе? (Например значение 1.03)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На случай, если (судя по вопросу) вы еще не знакомы со сторонними библиотеками, а список может быть неотсортированным  (о чем в вопросе - ни слова) -  то вот так:

```
lt=[0.3, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]

tl=1.03
im=0
ami=float("inf")
for i,a in enumerate(lt):
    if abs(tl-a)<ami:
        ami=abs(tl-a)
        im=i
print(lt[im])
```

Результат:

```
1.0
```

А можно и еще проще, в две строчки, вот так:

```
rs=list(map(lambda x:abs(x-tl),lt))
lt[rs.index(min(rs))]
```

с тем-же результатом.

Answer (score 2):

Считаем, что список всегда отсортированный, и число всегда попадает в диапазон между значениями первого и последнего элемента.

Задача решается с помощью [бинарного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), в Python для этого уже есть стандартный модуль [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).

С помощью `bisect_left` из модуля `bisect` находим индекс, куда нужно вставить искомое значение, чтобы список остался отсортированным. Дальше по этому индексу смотрим значения справа и слева, выбираем то, которое меньше отличается от искомого:

```
import bisect

s = [0.3, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]
x = 1.03
i = bisect.bisect_left(s, x)

print(min(s[i-1], s[i], key=lambda y: (x - y) ** 2))
# 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Так то вообще это делается указанием подходящего ключа для функции `min`:

```py
lst = [0.3, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]
z = 1.03
print(min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x - z)))
# 1.0
```

Никакие дополнительные изыски не нужны. Ну, разве что кроме случая отсортированных заранее данных, где двоичный поиск очень ускорит дело (ответ insolor).